# Autocomplete drupal

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, hidden

It's not a problem but i would like to learn how to get some other value.

```
function search_autocomplete($string) {
  $matches = array();
    $temp= array();


 $query = db_select('user','s');

  $return = $query
    ->fields('s')
    ->condition('lastname', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute();

  foreach ($return as $row) {
    $matches[$row->user_id] = check_plain($row->lastname).' '.($row->firstname);

  }
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

Now when search box appears when i start typing by last name i get user lets say Doe John. But when i press search button i get his user_id.

[image]

I know when i change user_id to lets say last name i get the last name when i search.

Now my question is how to get last and first name when search is clicked, but send the user_ID.

Answer (score 0):

The entity reference module handles it by putting the uid in brackets after the name:

```
foreach ($return as $row) {
    $key = check_plain($row->lastname).' '.($row->firstname).' ('.$row->user_id].')';
    $matches[$key] = check_plain($row->lastname).' '.($row->firstname);
}
```

Another (but more complex) option would be to create a hidden field to store the uid in.

Comment: Hmm, its giving me the value . It doesn't hide it . I have tried several things but user_ id is still visible...

Comment: Yes, the uid will be visible in brackets after the name. If you don't want it visible at all then you'll need to use a hidden field.